# Vuejs how to translate weekdays with i18

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization

In my `vue` I have this array of objects which contains weekdays for displaying opening hours. Now I have a multilanguage page, so I need to translate those weekdays in multiple languages. I want to use the [i18](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/)-plugin?

here is my array:

```
[
  {
    weekday: "Monday",
    open: true
    openingHours: [
      {
         open: "10:00:00"
         close: "15:00:00" 
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    weekday: "Tuesday",
    open: true
    openingHours: [
      {
         open: "10:00:00"
         close: "15:00:00" 
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    weekday: "Wednesday",
    open: true
    openingHours: [
      {
         open: "10:00:00"
         close: "18:00:00" 
      }
    ],
    open: true
  },
  {
    weekday: "Thursday",
    open: true
    openingHours: [
      {
         open: "10:00:00"
         close: "15:00:00" 
      }
    ],
  },
  etc etc...
]
```

then I created a global i18.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

const weekDays = {
   en: {
    weekdays: {
        Monday: 'Monday',
        Tuesday: 'Tuesday',
        Wednesday: 'Wednesday',
        Thursday: 'Thursday',
        Friday: 'Friday',
        Saturday: 'Saturday',
        Sunday: 'Sunday',
    },
  },
  de: {
    weekdays: {
        Monday: 'Montag',
        Tuesday: 'Dienstag',
        Wednesday: 'Mittwoch',
        Thursday: 'Donnerstag',
        Friday: 'Freitag',
        Saturday: 'Samstag',
        Sunday: 'Sonntag',
    },
  },
};

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'de',
  weekDays,
});

export default i18n;
```

and then in my `vue` file:

```
<div v-for="day in openHours" :key="day.id">
    <span>
       {{ $t('weekdays.' + day.weekday) }}
    </span>
 </div>
```

But this doesn't work and gives me the error `Cannot read property '_t' of undefined`. So, what am I doing wrong?

So, for german the desired result should be:

```
 Montag 10:00 - 15:00
 Dienstag 10:00 - 15:00
 // etc etc.
```

Can someone help me out?

**/////// UPDATE //////**

I changes `const weekDays` to `const messages`

now I get the error: `vue-i18n] Cannot translate the value of keypath 'Monday'. Use the value of keypath as default.`

Comment: The error meaning that translation plugin is not initialized and recognized. 
```export default i18n;``` did you imported this into your main js file correctly?

Comment: Yes, but I got a new error now.... :-/

Comment: please show your main js file also